# Reduce QGIS Docker image size

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, docker

I am using the Docker image from [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/qgis/qgis) to run a few Python scripts that use the following modules:

- qgis.core
- qgis.gui
- qgis.PyQt.QtGui

Uncompressed that Docker image is > 8GB in size. Is there any way to reduce the size, e.g. by deleting certain data?

Answer (score 3):

The official QGIS docker image requires that much space because it includes the complete source code, all the dependencies required to build QGIS (which are at least a couple of GB's heavy) and also build components such as the QGIS server.

You likely don't need anything of the aforementioned to run a few python scripts.

There are smaller images available on dockerhub for example by opengis.ch which basically only includes the final installed software and therefore is much more lightweight ([dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/opengisch/qgis/tags), [github](https://github.com/opengisch/qgis-docker)). This image seems to be 2GB in size uncompressed.

Comment: Thanks for this great hint! Is there really no pyqgis package on PyPi?